# OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files when invoking script from terminal

Tags: python, ubuntu-14.04, pycharm

Ubuntu 14.04, Pycharm 5.0.1, Python 3.4.3

I have a multi thread intensive script (over 1k) which uses lots of files and sockets it also produces lots of logs. The problem I am facing is very peculiar. Starting the script from pycharm works fine, however invoking the script from terminal produces after a while

```
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files.
```

the limits showed by

```
  ulimit -Hn
```

are over 100k, and once again starting from pycharm works fine, starting:

```
 python3 my_script.py
```

Produces the error, I even tried using sudo, no luck. Can anybody explain what is happening?

**EDIT**

Done some more testing and from the looks of if, it seems that starting the script by pycharm it starts as true multhireaded process and starting from bash does not. I base this on results of ps aux:

```
USER PID  %CPU %MEM VSZ RSS TTY STAT START TIME COMMAND
user1   * * * * *            ? Sl   17:38  73:30 /usr/bin/python3.4 /home/user1/new_main.py
user1   * * * * *            ? S+   17:40  71:30 python3.4 /home/user1/new_main.py
```

For those like me who need a small reference, here is an extract

```
STAT = multi-character process state
PROCESS STATE CODES
   Here are the different values that the s, stat and state output specifiers (header "STAT" or "S") will display to describe the state of a process:
   S    interruptible sleep (waiting for an event to complete)

   For BSD formats and when the stat keyword is used, additional characters may be displayed:
   l    is multi-threaded (using CLONE_THREAD, like NPTL pthreads do)
   +    is in the foreground process group.
```

So the system says that the script started by pycharm (Sl) is multithreaded and the other is not.

Comment: If you trim the code down to the bare minimum, can you replicate the error?  If so, can you post that code here?

Comment: The script is pretty long 1k+ lines

Comment: Also I dont think it is the code, in pycharm it works just fine, only invoking it  by hand prdouces the error

Comment: Like I said - trim it down to the absolute minimum necessary to replicate the error.  That's usually a few dozen lines of code at most.  You may well find the issue while you're doing this.  But even if it's not the code, by posting an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), others can attempt to replicate it.  This will give you a better shot at getting the answer.

Comment: Are you closing all the files and sockets after you don't need them anymore?

Comment: Is there a noticeable difference when running in the two environments in terms of execution speed or rates at which threads are spawned?

Comment: I dont think so. However, I will check that.

Comment: Done more testing the results are in the edit

Comment: This is an old issue, but here is some diagnosis info as I just encountered the same. It seems that Pycharm does not launch the Python script with different options, but runs it in a shell with a different environment configuration. On Mac OS X, in the terminal, `ulimit -n` yields 256, while it yields 10240 in the shell launched by Pycharm. Raising the limit in you terminal shell (with `ulimit -n new_value`) should solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe when you run your script using PyCharm, the IDE adds some options to the command line.

To find the command used by pycharm :

- run your program using pycharm.
- then (while your program runs) type in a terminal : `ps aux | grep my_script.py`

I had the same issue playing with multi threads and other file descriptors, a way to avoid the problem would probably be by optimizing your code, and / or reducing the maximal number of threads.

Comment: I also think it has something to do with ide invoking python in a different way. However, ps aux returned nothing just 
/usr/bin/python3.4 my_script.py

Comment: maybe it's the user launching the scripts that differs?

Comment: No the users are also the same according to the info returned by ps aux

Comment: I've done more testing and their is a difference, would you care to look at my edit?